# How to implement Moving Average in TradingView?

Tags: pine-script

I want to implement the Moving Average (MA) TradingView.

There are already some built-in functions for moving averages (like `sma()`, `ema()`, and `wma()`). Now I want to built my own MA function.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your question still relevant? If yes, then you need to understand what problems you have with building MA.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [manual](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_sma), `sma` **is** the standard `MA`.

> The sma function returns the moving average, that is the sum of last y
>   values of x, divided by y. 
>   `sma(source, length) → series`

But if you still insist, they also show you how to do it in `pine-script`, like this:

```js
// same in pine, but much less efficient
pine_sma(x, y) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sum := sum + x[i] / y
    sum
plot(pine_sma(close, 15))
```

Comment: How do you console.log in pine?

Comment: @zero_cool You don't. It is not JS based, but "invented" by T.V.

Comment: It's just an analogy to express what I'm looking to do. It's strange to invent a programming language that does not allow one to log to the console.

Comment: There is no console. If you search the TV Wiki pages, you can find ways to put some very simple text [like this](https://blog.tradingview.com/en/new-features-of-pine-script-language-893/) but you can't use variables for the text.

Comment: You can see the console underneath the script when you save. It indicates errors, and success. That's cool that you can put text in. If you could put variables in, that could be used as a substitute!

Comment: This doesn't compile on the latest release. Error is Script could not be translated from: for i = 0 to y. Any idea why? Was there a syntax update?

Comment: If a previously working script suddenly doesn't work in TV, then make sure to refresh the entire webpage (CTRL-R). TV's webpage is notoriously unstable when not regularly refreshed!

Answer (score 1):

```
from pine documentation,

my_sma(src, len) =>
    sum = 0.0
    sum := nz(sum[1]) - nz(src[len]) + src
    sum/len
```

And that is efficient.